# Error in nuxt deployment using npm run generate build command in netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

Hi a couple of years ago I deployed my web portfolio on Netlify, I created the portfolio with Nuxt.js. Today, I made an update to some texts and committed it to my repository on GitLab, but when I checked if it had already been deployed on Netlify, I found the following error in the deployment logs.

```
1:21:09 AM: ​
1:21:09 AM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
1:21:09 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1:21:09 AM: ​
1:21:09 AM: $ npm run generate
1:21:09 AM: > kevinburbano-devfolio@1.0.0 generate /opt/build/repo
1:21:09 AM: > nuxt generate
1:21:09 AM: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
1:21:09 AM:   throw err;
1:21:09 AM:   ^
1:21:09 AM: Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
1:21:09 AM: Require stack:
1:21:09 AM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/rc9/dist/index.cjs
1:21:09 AM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@nuxt/config/dist/config.js
1:21:09 AM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js
1:21:09 AM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli.js
1:21:09 AM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js
1:21:09 AM:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
1:21:09 AM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
1:21:09 AM:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
1:21:09 AM:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
1:21:09 AM:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/rc9/dist/index.cjs:3:17)
1:21:09 AM:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
1:21:09 AM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
1:21:09 AM:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
1:21:09 AM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
1:21:09 AM:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19) {
1:21:09 AM:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
1:21:09 AM:   requireStack: [
1:21:09 AM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/rc9/dist/index.cjs',
1:21:09 AM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@nuxt/config/dist/config.js',
1:21:09 AM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js',
1:21:09 AM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli.js',
1:21:09 AM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js'
1:21:09 AM:   ]
1:21:09 AM: }
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! errno 1
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! kevinburbano-devfolio@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR!
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! Failed at the kevinburbano-devfolio@1.0.0 generate script.
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
1:21:09 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T06_21_09_463Z-debug.log
1:21:09 AM: ​
1:21:09 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
1:21:09 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1:21:09 AM: ​
1:21:09 AM:   Error message
1:21:09 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run generate (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
1:21:09 AM: ​
1:21:09 AM:   Error location
1:21:09 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
1:21:09 AM:   npm run generate
1:21:09 AM: ​
1:21:09 AM:   Resolved config
1:21:09 AM:   build:
1:21:09 AM:     command: npm run generate
1:21:09 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
1:21:09 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
1:21:09 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
1:21:10 AM: Caching artifacts
1:21:10 AM: Started saving node modules
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving node modules
1:21:10 AM: Started saving build plugins
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving build plugins
1:21:10 AM: Started saving corepack cache
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving corepack cache
1:21:10 AM: Started saving pip cache
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving pip cache
1:21:10 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Started saving rust rustup cache
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
1:21:10 AM: Started saving go dependencies
1:21:10 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
1:21:11 AM: Cached Ruby version 2.7.1
1:21:11 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
1:21:11 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
1:21:11 AM: Finished processing build request in 54.015s
```

I don't know what's going on, as I didn't make any changes to the netlify configuration since it was working fine. I did some research and read in another post that I should use CI= npm run generate in the build command of netlify and create an environment variable CI=false. I tried this, but the issue still persists. Do you have any idea what else I can do? I returned my configuration to how it was before

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US1Gt.png)

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "kevinburbano-devfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Kevin Burbano developer portafolio",
  "author": "Kevin Burbano",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.5",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/router": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

I did some research and read in another post that I should use CI= npm run generate in the build command of netlify and create an environment variable CI=false. I tried this, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem is the version of node in the netlify environment, Netlify does not support Node v16, so setting the version manually in environment variable `NODE_VERSION=14` works for me.